# How can I uninstall TeamViewer (multiple versions) from all computers on a domain?

Tags: uninstall, domain, group-policy

We have switched our remote support software away from TeamViewer.

We have around 100 computers (multiple Windows versions) that have TeamViewer (multiple versions) installed that need to be uninstalled.

What is the best method to create some "dynamic" script that can be ran via Group Policy to detect the TeamViewer version and run the uninstaller silently in the background?

Comment: The many sites with similar topics are confusing, but this should be on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Peter this question does not concern servers. Thanks.

Comment: Irrelevant. http://serverfault.com/tour - see the- "ask about" part. Similarly, see the "Don't ask about" part on http://superuser.com/tour, specifically the last item. As I said, it can be slightly confusing at first